# Trying to call mysql stored procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The php is called through ajax from a button on a different page and I'm trying to remove a column from my database. The code runs all the way through, but changes nothing in the database. The function works when run in mysql work bench. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$facNum = $_POST['facNum'];


$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }


$sql = 'CALL makePositionVacant('. $facNum .')';


$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql  );


$retval;


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Might be a permissions thing when on main site. Check that the user has the permission to delete in the mySQL access and also check the function and it's permissions.

Comment: is it possible that the useraccount php is using doesn't have the privilege to run this SP?

Comment: ...so, here are two jeffs with the same comment... is this still coincidence??

Comment: Check the return value: `if (!$retval) { die(mysqli_error($conn)); }`

Comment: You should learn to use prepared queries instead of substituting variables into queries. Your code is subject to SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.